# Is there already a good canonical target for "`var x = func()` overriding `func x()`" JavaScript questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical

On Monday [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704757/function-call-javascript) got asked.  I misread it and flagged it as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), but retracted my vote after re-reading it as that's not a good dupe target for this specific issue.  I then went on my way as an answer had been posted.

Today [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747570/can-you-explain-this-weird-function-declaration-behavior) has been asked, so I'm thinking this is probably something that gets asked pretty frequently.  Is anyone aware of a high quality canonical Q&A that deals with this specific problem for the next time it crops up?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of marking the first question in there as duplicate of [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting).

Comment: I was hoping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname would mention it, but looks like none of the answers mention that case.

Comment: @epascarello Yeah that was my initial one that I retracted because I felt it didn't really cover it

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty of marking the first question in there as duplicate of [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting).

When one understands hoising, what's happening in the question you linked becomes obvious. It's the best I could find, so far.

Comment: Thanks - will add that to my list of targets. Not entirely sure it's a perfect fit for this issue, but it's certainly better than my initial choice!  I agree that if you think about what's being discussed in that one it should help you understand the original questions too - guess I was hoping we might already have one that spells out what's going on here since it seems to be a frequent one in itself.